# User Defined Functions llvm

Tags: function, llvm

I am writing a pass in `LLVM` in which I need information regarding all the `functions defined by user.`
Is there any procedure by which we can get user defined functions?
I am iterating over `Module and Function iterator` but how to check a given function is user defined or not?

Comment: What's a user defined function? And what isn't?

Comment: It means only the functions written by programmer and not library functions.

Comment: That's an insufficient (not to say useless) definition. All code is written by programmers (except automatically generated code, I guess -- and in those cases, programmers specified how it's generated, directly or indirectly). And whether something is a library or the main thing depends on who you ask -- for a CPython hacker, the functions in `libpython` are user-defined; for someone writing extension modules for Python, it's contents are "library functions". [What are you actually trying to achieve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Actually I am writing a pass on extracting the pointer in a program, and but it iterates over all the functions including library functions. Say I have a program in which I defined two functions main() and add(), then I want to extract information regarding these two functions only, not of all those library functions which are called by these two functions